# python - Weight for weight from CodeWars

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code works, but at the same time it outputs a string in which the same value can be reversed. Therefore, it gives an error in tests

Here is the code itself:

```
def order_weight(strng):
    weight = strng.split(' ')
    t_weight = weight.copy()
    answ = ''
    t_arr = []
    for i in range(len(weight)):
        t_min = 2**64
        t_index = 0
        t_num = 0
        for i, num in enumerate(t_weight):
            t_sum = 0
            for j in num:
                t_sum += int(j)
            if t_sum <= t_min:
                t_min = t_sum
                t_index = i
                t_num = num
        t_arr.append(t_num)
        t_weight.pop(t_index)
    answ = ' '.join(t_arr)
    return answ
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ma3z.png)

Comment: I'm new to programming, so many people will not understand why I wrote a lot of extra lines. I answer: I am learning to understand the construction of logic in programs, so now the code looks terrible, sorry

Comment: What do you want the function to do?

Comment: You should complete the question with an example call to the function (ex: `order_weight("45682312")`), and the expected output.

Comment: Here is the task condition: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c6126177c9441a570000cc/train/python

Comment: The function is called automatically thanks to CodeWars tests

Comment: The code performs its task correctly, but the tests do not accept the answer, because the order of output of numbers in it is different

Comment: Your code puts 22 before 10003, so not completely correct.

Comment: So I would like to figure out what the reason is, why?

Comment: You are making it overcomplex, it could be simplified lot - thinking about the final *goal*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it's harder to follow your logic, but this will be my simple approach:

Please read and compare with yours.  It's passed all tests too.

```py
def count_weight(s):
    return (sum(int(c) for c in s), s)

def order_weight(s):
    return ' '.join(sorted(s.split(' '), key=count_weight))  # use the *weight* as the sort_key here
```